# How to do multiple wilcox.test in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I have this matrix and aim to do Wilcoxon tests in R (controls vs cases) but I am not sure how to put in my matrix properly.

```
gene.name  cont1 cont2  cont3  case1  case2  case3
A           10    2      3      21     18      8
B           14    8      7      12     34      22
C           16    9      19     21     2       8
D           32    81     17     29     43      25
..
```

Comment: What have you tried? [The gCMAP package for R, and associated documentation](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/gCMAP.html) may be helpful.

Comment: I did that before but that does ttest  however I need to do Wilxcon test as my data is nonparametric

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
# load your data 
d <- read.table(text="gene.name  cont1 cont2  cont3  case1  case2  case3
A           10    2      3      21     18      8
B           14    8      7      12     34      22
C           16    9      19     21     2       8
B           32    81     17     29     43      25", header=T)

library(tidyverse)
# transform to long format using dplyr (included in tidyverse)
dlong <- as.tbl(d) %>% 
  gather(key, value,-gene.name) %>% 
  mutate(group=ifelse(grepl("cont",key), "control", "case"))
# plot the data
dlong %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=group, y=value)) +
   geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

```
# run the test
dlong %>% 
  with(., wilcox.test(value ~ group))

Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction

data:  value by group
W = 94.5, p-value = 0.2034
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0
```

## Edits

```
# as you don't clarified how to handle the double occurence of B I assume 
# thats a typo and fixed the second B to D
library(ggpubr)
dlong <- as.tbl(d) %>%
  mutate(gene.name=LETTERS[1:4]) %>% 
  gather(key, value,-gene.name) %>% 
  mutate(group=ifelse(grepl("cont",key), "control", "case"))

# plot the boxplot with Wilcoxen p-values using ggpubr
dlong %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=gene.name, y=value, fill=group)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_compare_means(method= "wilcox.test")
```

[image]

```
# get the pvalues
dlong %>% 
  group_by(gene.name) %>% 
  summarise(p=wilcox.test(value~group)$p.value)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
   gene.name     p
       <chr> <dbl>
1         A   0.2
2         B   0.2
3         C   0.7
4         D   1.0
```

Or try base R using apply.

```
res <- apply(d[,-1], 1, function(x){
  wilcox.test(x ~ c(1,1,1,2,2,2))$p.value
})
cbind.data.frame(Genes=as.character(d$gene.name), p=res, BH=p.adjust(res, method = "BH"))
     Genes   p        BH
[1,]     1 0.2 0.4000000
[2,]     2 0.2 0.4000000
[3,]     3 0.7 0.9333333
[4,]     2 1.0 1.0000000
```

Comment: Thanks Jimbou. But I need a list of genes with P-value for each gene (row by row). Or alternatively getting the list of genes that pass P-value<0.05.

Comment: SOMEBODY HELP PLEASE! What I WANT is just A SIMPLE U-TEST but I dont know how to put in my matrix ????

Comment: @Behmah first you have to explain why B occures twice, and how to handle it? As independent measurements or repeated ones or as own group?

Comment: It worked well. Just about the second solution (base R apply) How can I write the result and also the name of genes (I have a big list of genes) ?